how to print curl response json parse using shell script
I have an API or Endpoint below endpoint use GET method:
https://test.cloudnetwork/devops/api/status?over=658xx899xxx68sspo

its response below one
{
  "info": testing of cloudnetwork data soon,
   "test1": [ "reading test" ],
   "test2": "FAILED",
   "test3": { },
    test4": {
        "test4.1": "FAILED",
        "test4.2": [
            {
            },   
        ]
       },
    "test5": {
        "test5.1": "FAILED",
        "test5.2": [

After this we have so many response coming similar to test 4 and test 5 like test 6 and test 7 continue
Here is my small shellscript I have written:
if [ "$WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION" == "true" ]; then
    echo "My message to complete..."

    test4.1="PROCESSING"
    while [[ "$test4.1" == "PROCESSING" ]]; do
        TEST_STATUS=$(curl -s --location --request GET "https://test.cloudnetwork/devops/api/status?over=$OVER_ID" \
          --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN")
        echo ""
        test1=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.errorsDetected[]')
        TEST=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.test4')
        test4.1=$(echo "$test4" | jq -r '.status')
        if [ "$test4.1" == "FAILED" ]; then
             test4.1=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.test4.test4.1')
            echo " "
            echo "Test Status: $STATUS"
            if [ -z "$TEST_4" ] || [ "$TEST_4" == "null" ]; then
                echo "Build failed test4.1.   $TEST_4"
                exit 1
            fi
        fi 
    done

    # Once the status is no longer "PROCESSING," assume it completed
    echo "my message completed successfully!"
else
    echo "my message failed"
    exit 1
fi

I'm able to print above message which is coming in response using above shell script.
Can you help me out with just what do I need to change in shell script to get above full response with status showing FAILED OR PASSED OR SUCCESSFULLY?

Step one for shell script problems should always be a visit to https://www.shellcheck.net/

Potential issues in the script-

Rename test4.1 to test4_1 to ensure compatibility with shell variable naming.

Set test4_1 directly from the JSON response for accurate data extraction.

Make sure the loop correctly waits until test4_1 is no longer "PROCESSING" to proceed.


You can update the script like below -
if [ "$WAIT_FOR_COMPLETION" == "true" ]; then
    echo "My message to complete..."

    test4_1="PROCESSING"
   
    while [[ "$test4_1" == "PROCESSING" ]]; do
        
        # Fetch the response
        TEST_STATUS=$(curl -s --location --request GET "https://test.cloudnetwork/devops/api/status?over=$OVER_ID" \
          --header "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN")

        # Print the full JSON response
        echo "Full response:"
        echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq .

        # Parse individual fields from the JSON response
        test1=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.test1[]')
        test2=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.test2')
        test4_1=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.test4.test4.1')
        test5_1=$(echo "$TEST_STATUS" | jq -r '.test5.test5.1')

        # Print statuses
        echo "Test1 Status: $test1"
        echo "Test2 Status: $test2"
        echo "Test4.1 Status: $test4_1"
        echo "Test5.1 Status: $test5_1"

        # Check if any of the statuses indicate failure
        if [[ "$test4_1" == "FAILED" || "$test5_1" == "FAILED" ]]; then
            echo "Build failed in test4.1 or test5.1. Status: FAILED"
            exit 1
        fi

        # If "PROCESSING" is complete
        if [[ "$test4_1" != "PROCESSING" ]]; then
            echo "Test completed with status: SUCCESSFULLY"
            break
        fi

        # Sleep to avoid rapid looping
        sleep 5
    done

    echo "My message completed successfully!"
else
    echo "My message failed"
    exit 1
fi


Don't just post code, explain what was wrong with the OP's code and how you fixed it. E.g. variable names can't contain ..
